# MATLAB: give IDs to points stored in a matrix to distinguish between neighbours

Tags: matlab, matrix, point, identifier

Even though the title might sound trivial at first, I hope someone can help me by giving me hints about the MATLAB functions I can use:

I have a matrix of points with properties for each (read: individuals with properties) of the form (x, y, direction):

```
A = [1 1  45°]
B = [3 1 225°]
C = [0 2  90°]
D = [5 5 187°]
```

With a probablity P particle A chooses one of B and C as neighbours and turns it direction according to its neighbour (while D is too far away) **EDIT** *and moves towards it with a constant velocity (I basically forgot the most important part of the question ..., stupid me)*.

I have now implemented a matrix called:

```
I = [1 1 45; 3 1 225; 0 2 90; 5 5 187];
```

In a scenario A chooses C (randomly) as attractive neighbour and turns towards C. This means my program has to be able to distinguish between B and C.

Does there maybe exist a type like "point" where you can store properties with an ID? Do I have to use Vectors instead of one matrix? I am right now working with a lot of individuals, so preallocating 50 vectors would be not optimal (this is why  chose a matrix).

To make a clear question:
I have a lot of points, I need to store 3 properties to an ID for each point and then check for one point with IDx which other points with IDy's are within reach.
The mathematics are irrelevant for now, but I need a function in MATLAB that gives a better option than storing these information in a matrix (because that one seems not good for identifying each point). This is part of a flocking simulation for individuals.

If anyone can help me with this I would be very happy! If I asked that question in a bad way please give me feedback as well to clarify.
Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand your problem with using one big matrix. Aren't your IDs corresponding with the row indices?

Comment: What is a lot of individuals? 100? 1000? 1000000? I imagine that neighbor relations change during simulation, so you cannot pre-compute a distance matrix? If so, you'd want to use an R-tree to store individuals. That's a data structure that allows efficiently searching for all individuals in a neighborhood, or even k-nearest neighbors. But if you are dealing with only 100 individuals, you might be able to do brute force search also. The distance matrix is an NxN matrix, with N the number of individuals, where each matrix element (I,J) is the distance between individuals I and J.

Comment: I added the point above, about the movement ... I somehow was so into the topic I thought it would be clear, that if the point turns, it also moves, but yeah, after rereading it I see that that gave a very wrong impression ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from you, the following can be done:

When you store your elements in the original matrix, let the row index be their ID.

Since points do not change locations but only orientation, then you can compute only once a matrix or relative distances (Upper triangle matrix with size n^2).

In the distance matrix use the IDs you have from your first matrix as IDs for the same objects in the second matrix. Your search will be a min-search over ~0.5*n^2 elements.

Comment: Ah I see this is well explained! I have gotten a much better idea about the structure.Since I assume the points being static within a timestep, I would have to recalculate the distance matrix in every time step right and then move the each point according to its direction (I added that bit of information in the question, because it was unclear written, my bad ...)